# Retrieve name of a list from a list of lists

Tags: r

I have a list of lists.
`all_lists <- list(list1, list2, list3, ...)`

Now, I want to retrieve just the name of each list to create a table, so I thought something like this would work (let's say I want to get only "list1" as output):

`all_lists[[1]]`

I was wrong. It gives me `A tibble: 261 × 43` and the first 10 objects or list1, as if I used head().

If I use `names(all_lists[[1]])` it gives me the columns names of list1

**How can I get only "list1" as output**.
I know I can build the table by selecting every single list name, but I'm working with a bunch of lists and I'm searching for something more "clean"

Comment: Try `attributes(all_lists)`, if you get `NULL` you have an unnamed list.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `names` on a single element of the list, but you want a single element of `names(list)`.
Subset outside the call to `names`

```
names(all_lists)[[1]]
```

Comment: Tried, it gives me "NULL" as output

Comment: that is probably because your list elements do not actually have names, see the answer by @RonakShah

Answer (score 0):

`all_lists` does not have the information that you want.

I may suggest two options -

1. Assign names manually.

```
all_lists <- list(list1 = list1, list2 = list2,list3 =  list3, ...)
```

2. Use `dplyr::lst` which does the same thing but without explicitly specifying the names.

```
all_lists <- dplyr::lst(list1, list2, list3, ...)
```

After using any of the above you may get the names of the list by doing `names(all_lists)[1]`.

---

Using a reproducible example -

```
tmp <- head(mtcars, 2)
list1 <- tmp
list2 <- tmp
list3 <- tmp

all_lists <- list(list1, list2, list3)

all_lists

#[[1]]
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#[[2]]
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#[[3]]
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

If you check the contents of `all_lists` there is no information like `list1`, `list2` etc.

Now if you use `dplyr::lst` instead.

```
all_lists <- dplyr::lst(list1, list2, list3)
all_lists

#$list1
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#$list2
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#$list3
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

You can see the name of the list which can be retrieved using `names`.

```
names(all_lists)
#[1] "list1" "list2" "list3"

#Or a single name
names(all_lists)[1]
#[1] "list1"
```